# pgAdmin 4 - Can't Create Script on a database

Tags: pgadmin, mac-os-x, pgadmin-4

When I try to `CREATE Script` on a database I want to use, there is no `CREATE Script` item in the context menu.
[image: No CREATE Script option]
But `CREATE Script` looks fine on another database. I can select it and it works fine.
[image: with CREATE Script option]
Similarly, `CREATE Script` in the `Object` menu looks fine when I'm on the other database, but is disabled when I'm on the one that I want.

Is this just some permissions that I don't have on the main database?

My user role is:

```
CREATE USER [redacted] WITH
  LOGIN
  NOSUPERUSER
  INHERIT
  NOCREATEDB
  NOCREATEROLE
  NOREPLICATION;

GRANT [redacted], [redacted] TO [redacted];
```

I'm using pgAdmin 4 version 1.6 on Mac OS X El Capitan v 10.11.6.

Answer (score 1):

This `CREATE Script` option won't display in the context menu if you are connecting to the server with a user that does not have the `SUPERUSER` 
privilege or which does not have the `CREATEDB` privilege.

Comment: ...does that mean I can't run a query? I don't want to add or drop tables, I just want to run something like `select this, that from some_table` ... surely there's a way I can do that without having `SUPERUSER` or `CREATEDB`? 

I'm assuming there's some really obvious thing here that I'm not seeing...

Comment: ...or is 'CREATE Script' not the right command to simply write a select query?

Comment: `CREATE Script` will open query tool with the SQL shown on main SQL tab, It is helpful creating same database objects, For example let say if you have `Database_1` and you want to create `Database_2` with the same options/parameters as `Database_1` you can use this option, for SELECT operation, you will see another context menu option which will look like `SELECT Script` when you right click on either `Table` or `View` objects.

Comment: FYI, Newer version of pgAdmin4 is now available which is pgAdmin4 v2.0 if you are interested :)

Comment: Thanks @n33rma for your feedback, I've downloaded v2.0 but still can't see `SELECT Script` anywhere. Then again, I can't see any tables or views inside `pg_default` or `pg_global`, so perhaps that's my problem...

Comment: I am able to see it with non-super user, Check screenshots https://ibb.co/fRpFvw    https://ibb.co/ksix8G